# How to fix the nodejs (mariadb/mysql) connection slow speed issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to trouble shoot/fix my nodejs apis:

My following services are being stuck at somewhere.

```
 http://localhost:3001/api/designs/1
and http://localhost:3001/api/financial/getlist/0/6/100
```

my services are very simple services, both are getting the details on the bases or providing ids.

When I tried to debug/trouble shoot the services' issue then both are running smoothly but when i try to call from an client application then it is being stuck at somewhere.

Client side is very simple as well. I event checked through my stored procedure by calling it manually. It is getting data quickly within milli-seconds.

this is my client code

```
  let pageDesignApiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_DESIGNAPI + "/" + pageId;
            const response = await fetch(pageDesignApiUrl);
            const json = await response.json();
            const resultPages = json && json.page ? json.page[0] : "";



===_service-controller.js====================================
```

this is my nodejs service code

```
const getDesignById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const Id = req.params.id;  
    let Detail;
    try {
        Detail = await query("CALL spGetPagedesignSettingsById(?)", [Id]);
    } catch (err) {
        const error = new HttpError("Something went wrong, could not find a page.", 500);
        return next(error);
    }

    if (!Detail) {
        const error = new HttpError("Could not find design setting for the provided id.", 404);
        return next(error);
    }

    res.json({ page: Detail && Detail.length > 0 ? Detail[0] : [] });
};
```

and this is second service code

```
const getList = async (req, res, next) => {
    let pageNo = req.params.pageNo;
    let pageSize = req.params.pageSize;
    let detailPageSize = req.params.detailPageSize;
    let detail;
    let styles;
    let colours;
    let doors;
    let finish;
    let features;
    let handles;
    try {
        detail = await query("CALL spGetPList(?,?)", [pageSize, pageNo]);

        styles = await query("CALL spGetSList(?,?)", [detailPageSize, pageNo]);
        colours = await query("CALL spGetCList(?,?)", [detailPageSize, pageNo]);
        doors = await query("CALL spGetDList(?,?)", [detailPageSize, pageNo]);
        finish = await query("CALL spGetFList(?,?)", [detailPageSize, pageNo]);
        features = await query("CALL spGetFeaList(?,?)", [detailPageSize, pageNo]);
        handles = await query("CALL spGetHanList(?,?)", [detailPageSize, pageNo]);
    } catch (err) {
        const error = new HttpError("Something went wrong, could not find a kitchen.", 500);
        return next(error);
    }

    if (!detail) {
        const error = new HttpError("Could not find detail for the provided id.", 404);
        return next(error);
    }
    res.json({
        list: detail && detail.length > 0 ? detail[0] : [],
        styles: styles && styles.length > 0 ? styles[0] : [],
        colours: colours && colours.length > 0 ? colours[0] : [],
        doors: doors && doors.length > 0 ? doors[0] : [],
        finishes: finish && finish.length > 0 ? finish[0] : [],
        features: features && features.length > 0 ? features[0] : [],
        handles: handles && handles.length > 0 ? handles[0] : [],
    });
};
```

==============================================connection.js====================================

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "temp",
    password: "test123",
    database: "temp1",
    port: 3306,
    debug: true,
    multipleStatements: true,
});

let query = function (sql, values) {
    // returns a Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                if (connection) {
                    connection.release();
                }
                reject(err);
            } else {
                connection.query(sql, values, (err, rows, fields) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        //callback(null, { err, rows, fields });
                        resolve(rows);
                        //resolve({ err, rows, fields });
                    }
                    // end the session
                    connection.release();
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
module.exports = query;
```

====================================Nodejs package.json=====================================

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "a project ",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
        "sharp": "^0.29.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --inspect index.js",
        "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=9229 index.js"
    },   
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

After that, It seems like database connection is being established again and again and taking much time at some where.

Is there a way to trouble and fix this issue. the issue seems to a connection issue but i am not 100% sure.